# Why "unique" field in creating a schema does't work?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a schema and i want the username field to be unique but it's not working (The "required" works normally). What i did try: restart mongodb, drop database. May i know what i am missing ?

Here is my schema:

```
import mongoose, { HookNextFunction, model } from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { AdminDocument } from '../interfaces';

const AdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    role: { type: Number, enum: [0, 1], required: true },
    address: { type: String },
    phone: { type: String, required: true },
    photo: { type: String, default: null },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    gender: { type: Number, enum: [0, 1, 2], required: true },
    refreshToken: { type: String, default: null },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

AdminSchema.pre('save', async function (next: HookNextFunction) {
  let user = this as AdminDocument;

  if (!user.isModified('password')) {
    return next();
  }
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(Number(process.env.SALT_WORK_FACTOR));
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

  user.password = hashedPassword;

  return next();
});

AdminSchema.methods.comparePassword = async function (
  candidatePassword: string
) {
  const user = this as AdminDocument;
  const isValid = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, user.password);
  return isValid;
};

export default model<AdminDocument>('Admin', AdminSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Mongoose connection script enable these options `useCreateIndex` and `autoIndex` to become true.

```js
mongoose
    .connect('connection url', {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true, //make this true
        autoIndex: true, //make this also true
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected to mongoDB');
    });
```

then drop the schemas from your db.

Comment: i am using mongoose v6, useCreateIndex is not supported in v6

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by creating an index using mongodb compass. But the problem is that i can not use the schema.index() method to createIndex for username field and i have also tried set the index: true and unique: true in username property, both are not working. Why is that ?

Here is what i have tried on mongoose schema index method:

```
AdminSchema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true });
console.log(AdminSchema.indexes());
```